# How to debug a SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I am still struggling with the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning which I get in the middle of a complex data processing:

```
df.a = df.a.str.upper()
```

Could you please show me how to produce such a `df` *on purpose*?

In my case, `df` is a result of the following sequence of calls:

```
df = pd.concat(..., ignore_index=True)
df.rename(..., inplace=True)
df.dropna(subset="a", inplace=True)
df.a = df.a.str.upper()
```

The list of frames concatenated to get `df` should not be relevant as `pd.concat` copies its arguments.

Comment: `df.a = df.a.str.upper()` should not raise anything unless df has been a copy of another df somewhere in your code, can you show us the very first time you set `df`

Comment: @StevenG: see the edit

Comment: it might be from one the dataframe you concat, you gonna have to retrace those too.